# PictureBox scaling horrifically in VB6

Tags: vb6, picturebox

I'm programming in Visual Basic 6.0 at the moment, just for fun.
I've come across an annoying issue that if I try and scale my pictures at all at **runtime** then it blurs and I can't read the text on the picture. If I scale it at **design** time then it scales just fine.

The picture is in 24-bit Bitmap file type, the same results come with using .gif or .jpeg also. VB6 doesn't handle PNG's as far as I'm aware. PictureBox's don't anyway.

Code for drawing at runtime: (correct aspect ratio)

```
Picture1.PaintPicture map, 0, 0, 700, 547
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening or if I'm doing it wrong?

I realise VB6 is out-dated and not supported, but as I say I am using it for a fun project.

Design time quality:
[image]

Run time quality:
[image]

Run time quality in VS2017 (C#):
[image]

Comment: This has to do with the default ROP (Raster OPeration) used by the StretchBlt function that underlies what VB6 is doing. I can't recall the details offhand, but if you do your own StretchBlt you can choose a more appropriate ROP. Google "Raster OPs".

Comment: While my apps (accounting) are not graphics intensive by any means, I bought third-party controls for images.  I seem to recall that it uses ImageMan which I'm sure, like nearly all third-party OCX controls developers is long since either out of business or otherwise no longer available, but if your app is graphics intensive I would consider researching to see what's out there in COM controls.

Comment: Read this one here: [How to scale, zoom, pan an image in anti-alias?](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?556973-RESOLVED-How-to-scale-zoom-pan-an-image-in-anti-alias)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UserControl implementation that you can use instead of a PictureBox control that uses StretchBlt for better quality:

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin VB.UserControl ImageBox 
   ClientHeight    =   648
   ClientLeft      =   0
   ClientTop       =   0
   ClientWidth     =   720
   ClipControls    =   0   'False
   ForwardFocus    =   -1  'True
   ScaleHeight     =   54
   ScaleMode       =   3  'Pixel
   ScaleWidth      =   60
   Begin VB.PictureBox picBuffer 
      AutoRedraw      =   -1  'True
      AutoSize        =   -1  'True
      BorderStyle     =   0  'None
      Height          =   372
      Left            =   120
      ScaleHeight     =   31
      ScaleMode       =   3  'Pixel
      ScaleWidth      =   36
      TabIndex        =   0
      Top             =   120
      Visible         =   0   'False
      Width           =   432
   End
End
Attribute VB_Name = "ImageBox"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
'###############################################################################
'#
'# ImageBox
'#
'###############################################################################

Option Explicit

'###############################################################################
'### Constants #################################################################
'###############################################################################

Private Const STRETCH_ANDSCANS = 1
Private Const STRETCH_DELETESCANS = 3
Private Const STRETCH_HALFTONE = 4
Private Const STRETCH_ORSCANS = 2
Private Const SRCCOPY = &HCC0020

'###############################################################################
'### APIs ######################################################################
'###############################################################################

Private Declare Function StretchBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, _
                                                   ByVal x As Long, _
                                                   ByVal y As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nWidth As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nHeight As Long, _
                                                   ByVal hSrcDC As Long, _
                                                   ByVal xSrc As Long, _
                                                   ByVal ySrc As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nSrcWidth As Long, _
                                                   ByVal nSrcHeight As Long, _
                                                   ByVal dwRop As Long) _
                                                   As Long
Private Declare Function SetStretchBltMode Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, _
                                                      ByVal nStretchMode As Long) _
                                                      As Long

'###############################################################################
'### Data ######################################################################
'###############################################################################

'###############################################################################
'### Events ####################################################################
'###############################################################################

Event Click()
Event DblClick()
Event MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
Event MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
Event MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)

'###############################################################################
'### Public Methods ############################################################
'###############################################################################

'*******************************************************************************
Public Property Get BackColor() As OLE_COLOR
Attribute BackColor.VB_Description = "Returns/sets the background color used to display text and graphics in an object."
   BackColor = UserControl.BackColor
End Property
Public Property Let BackColor(ByVal New_BackColor As OLE_COLOR)
   UserControl.BackColor() = New_BackColor
   PropertyChanged "BackColor"
End Property

'*******************************************************************************
Public Property Get Enabled() As Boolean
Attribute Enabled.VB_Description = "Returns/sets a value that determines whether an object can respond to user-generated events."
   Enabled = UserControl.Enabled
End Property
Public Property Let Enabled(ByVal New_Enabled As Boolean)
   UserControl.Enabled() = New_Enabled
   PropertyChanged "Enabled"
End Property

'*******************************************************************************
Public Property Get BorderStyle() As Integer
Attribute BorderStyle.VB_Description = "Returns/sets the border style for an object."
   BorderStyle = UserControl.BorderStyle
End Property
Public Property Let BorderStyle(ByVal New_BorderStyle As Integer)
   UserControl.BorderStyle() = New_BorderStyle
   PropertyChanged "BorderStyle"
End Property

'*******************************************************************************
Public Sub Refresh()
Attribute Refresh.VB_Description = "Forces a complete repaint of a object."
   Call UserControl.Refresh
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
Public Property Get Picture() As Picture
   Set Picture = picBuffer.Picture
End Property
Public Property Set Picture(ByVal New_Picture As Picture)
   Set picBuffer.Picture = New_Picture
   PropertyChanged "Picture"
   Me.Refresh
End Property

'###############################################################################
'### GUI Events ################################################################
'###############################################################################

'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_Click()
   RaiseEvent Click
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_DblClick()
   RaiseEvent DblClick
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
   RaiseEvent MouseDown(Button, Shift, x, y)
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
   RaiseEvent MouseMove(Button, Shift, x, y)
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
   RaiseEvent MouseUp(Button, Shift, x, y)
End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_Paint()

   Dim lSave As Long

   'set the stretchblit mode (saving the previous value)
   lSave = SetStretchBltMode(UserControl.hdc, STRETCH_HALFTONE)

   'perform blit
   Call StretchBlt(UserControl.hdc, 0, 0, UserControl.ScaleWidth, _
                     UserControl.ScaleHeight, picBuffer.hdc, 0, 0, _
                     picBuffer.ScaleWidth, picBuffer.ScaleHeight, SRCCOPY)

   'restore previous mode
   Call SetStretchBltMode(UserControl.hdc, lSave)

End Sub

'###############################################################################
'### UserControl Events ########################################################
'###############################################################################

'*******************************************************************************
' Initialize Properties for User Control
'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_InitProperties()

   'Set any defaults that should be saved from design-time to run-time here
   UserControl.Enabled = True

End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
' Load property values from storage
'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_ReadProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)

   'Set any values that were saved from design-time to run-time
   UserControl.BackColor = PropBag.ReadProperty("BackColor", &H8000000F)
   UserControl.Enabled = PropBag.ReadProperty("Enabled", True)
   UserControl.BackStyle = PropBag.ReadProperty("BackStyle", 1)
   UserControl.BorderStyle = PropBag.ReadProperty("BorderStyle", 0)
   Set Picture = PropBag.ReadProperty("Picture", Nothing)

End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
' Write property values to storage
'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_WriteProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)

   'Store any values that should be saved from design-time to run-time here
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("BackColor", UserControl.BackColor, &H8000000F)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("Enabled", UserControl.Enabled, True)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("BackStyle", UserControl.BackStyle, 1)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("BorderStyle", UserControl.BorderStyle, 0)
   Call PropBag.WriteProperty("Picture", Picture, Nothing)

End Sub

'*******************************************************************************
' Terminate fires when the form unloads.
'*******************************************************************************
Private Sub UserControl_Terminate()
   '
End Sub

'###############################################################################
'### Private Methods ###########################################################
'###############################################################################


'###############################################################################
'###############################################################################
'###############################################################################
```